# Class 'Spatie\Browsershot\Browsershot' not found in C:\wamp64\www\html\index.php

Tags: php, node.js

I'm trying to use browsershot (I'm using WAMP to host my local server) and basically I just try to create an instance of the class Browsershot() and it gives me this error :

> Class 'Spatie\Browsershot\Browsershot' not found in
>   C:\wamp64\www\html\index.php

I've tried redownloading both node and browsershot but nothing worked, I'm stuck. (I have a node 10 version and a PHP 7)

```
<?php 
use Spatie\Browsershot\Browsershot;
$browser = new Browsershot();
?>
```

Comment: Have you done a `composer require spatie/browsershot`? After that you'll need to include the composer autoloader.

Comment: @khartnett How do I include the composer autoloader?

Comment: if you're not using a framework or anything, composer autoloader should be in something like /vendor/autoload.php. So depending on where that is in relation to your index file, something like `require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';` should do it

Comment: // autoload.php @generated by Composer

require_once __DIR__ . '/composer/autoload_real.php';
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

return ComposerAutoloaderInit7f01534c0a26da857e24b07c1e58261a::getLoader();

Comment: this is what I found in the autoload file in vendor, and I've added what you told me but it still doesn't work.

Comment: could you update what you have in your index file?

Comment: I only have one file which is index, I've got nothing.

Comment: And I did composer update but nothing changed.

Comment: in your index file, add `require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';` above your `use Spatie\Browsershot\Browsershot;` line

Comment: Thank you so much it works perfectly now. I just have another question

Browsershot::url('www.google.com')->save($pathToImage);

When I do this, it gives me this error
 Call to undefined method Spatie\Browsershot\Browsershot::url()
It's really scratching my brain!

Comment: @Ramzi Benounis: please remember to accept the answer as it was helpful in addressing the challenge you faced. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the following directory structure:

```
+ YourApp
    + vendor
        + composer
        + guzzle
        + intervention
        + ...
        - autoload.php
    - composer.json
    - composer.lock
    - index.php
```

Use following in index.php:

```
<?php
use Spatie\Browsershot\Browsershot;

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$browser = new Browsershot();
```

Comment: Thank you so much it works perfectly now. I just have another question Browsershot::url('www.google.com')->save($pathToImage); When I do this, it gives me this error Call to undefined method Spatie\Browsershot\Browsershot::url() It's really scratching my brain!

Comment: Browsershot requires node 7.6.0 or higher and the Puppeteer Node library. Do you also have Puppeteer (you didn't mention it)?

Comment: I figured it out! I was supposed to create an instance of Browsershot first then use it, thanks again!